# How to clone a repo without downloading the repo history (due to file size), but also keep the knowledge of remote branches?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to clone a repo without downloading the repo history (due to disk space), but also keep the knowledge of remote branches?

I tried doing `git clone xxxxxxxxx.git --depth 1` but when I tried to checkout other branches, git didn't know they existed in remote, even after a `git fetch --all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt) using depth implies `--single-branch` unless `--no-single-branch` is specified.
Try adding `--no-single-branch`

Whole command is:

`git clone xxxxxxxxx.git --depth 1 --no-single-branch --shallow-submodules`

Answer (score 0):

Using the git documentation on depth ([here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt)), my finished command is the follows:

`git clone xxxxxxxxx.git --depth 1 --no-single-branch --shallow-submodules`

Comment: Can I ask why is your own answer is the accepted one? Posted mine earlier, pointed to the documentation and the `--no-single-branch` solves the problem. You didn't mention the submodules part in the question.

Comment: I'll accept yours. I just added mine since it has the whole command. Can you edit your answer to add the command as a whole? Then I'll delete this answer.